# Почему RegEx не находит текст в Java?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Кратко суть: программа-калькулятор, на вход строка с выражением типа 2+3*(4+6), любой сложности, на выход результат выражения по всем правилам математики.

Не пойму, почему регулярка:

```
Pattern patternPairOfAddOrSub = Pattern.compile("(/A|[^*/])(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)([+|-])(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(/Z|[^*/])");
Matcher matcher = patternPairOfAddOrSub.matcher("2+4+5");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

не находит текст 2+4 в выражении из примера в коде.

Что интересно, та же регулярка, с адаптацией под сайт,

```
(\A|[^*\/])(-?\d+\.?\d*)([+|-])(\d+\.?\d*)(\Z|[^*\/])
```

на [сайте](https://regex101.com) находит все правильно.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему у вас слеши не обратные на точках начала и конца строки?

Comment: @Visman и правда, невнимательность. спасибо.

Comment: У меня этот код `true` печатает. Java 1.8.

Comment: @zRrr хех.. странно

Comment: Т.е. с оригинальной строкой с `?` после первой и последней групп она работала, сейчас нет, но замена `/` на `\\\`, как указал Visman, помогает

Comment: @zRrr , да, знак вопроса там оказался случайно, это я тестил, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо найти "5+4+" в строке "2+4+5", используйте

```
(\A|[^*/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([+-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\Z|[^*/])
```

См. [демо здесь](https://regex101.com/r/fS6cO3/2).

Изменены:

- `/A`/`/Z` на `\A`/`\Z`
- `-?\d+\.?\d*` на `-?\d+(?:\.?\d+)?` чтобы избежать совпадений при `56.`
- `[+|-]` на `[+-]`, чтобы не было совпадений в случае `|`.

[Демо-код](http://ideone.com/r5Vk7X):

```
String rx = "(\\A|[^*/])(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)([+-])(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(\\Z|[^*/])";
Pattern patternPairOfAddOrSub = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = patternPairOfAddOrSub.matcher("2+4+5");
System.out.println(matcher.find()); // => true
```

Comment: еще изменил `[^*/]` на `[+(-]` и `[+)-]` @stribizhev

Comment: Да, кажется, я забыл упомянуть, что экранировать слеш в регулярном выражении для Java не нужно.